# Javascript object to behave differently, based on index ending: foo vs. foo()

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Is it possible to construct an object in a way to return the following:

```
baseObject.foo;   // return a string describing what foo does
baseObject.foo(); // execute the foo function

baseObject.bar;   // bar description
baseObject.bar(); // execute bar
```

Update: [JavaScript Method Overloading](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/) is close, but not quite what I'm looking for.

Update2: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/KKGqq/3/) (of solutions provided below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`baseObject.foo` has to be a function, otherwise you won't be able to call it. The only thing you can influence is how this function is coerced to a string, by overriding its `toString()` method. By default `toString()` returns function source code, you can make it return something else instead.

```
baseObject.foo = function() {
    // Do something
}
baseObject.foo.toString = function() {
    return "Function does something";
}
alert(baseObject.foo);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can overwrite the default `toString` method of the function:

```
baseObject.foo = function () { console.log('executing foo') }
baseObject.foo.toString = function () { return 'This function outputs "executing foo"'; }
```